# unity3d ios xcode error ,google VR sdk

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

[image]

I am using xphone in the Iphone package error, I built a new project only googleVR a plug

Iphone 6sp,IOS11
unity 5.6.2
GoogleVRForUnity_1.70.0.unitypackage

Answer (score 0):

you must open the workspace containing the project (not the project itself) in XCode and build and run the project there. 
Run from "Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace" instead of "Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj"

Comment: But I packaged out from unity without you say Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace。
Can you give a detailed step?